# Output text formatting date

Tags: visualforce

I am formatting my date field in visual force email template using output text.
the date what i have in the record is "28 december 2015"
End Date -> 28 December  2015

```
     <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM d, YYYY}">
     <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.End_Date__c}"/>
```

But The value is formatted as 28 December 2016

Answer (score 1):

yyyy--> should be small letters other wise it is rounding up the year

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the below example for reference...

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: not able to find any example

Comment: still it is not working.It Is showing up the same

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, d MMMM yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.End_Date__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Output for today is: 27 July 2015. (Sorry was a little late to see that you had actually answered your own question already ;))